# Q: How to create a Login using StreamReader in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, streamreader

So, I'm trying to create a **Login** system that gets the necessary information (name and password) from text file by using StreamReader.

**My Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace PizzaOrder
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {

        public int attempts = 0;
        public bool success = false;
        public bool usernameSuccess = false;
        public bool passwordSuccess = false;

        public static string LogIn = @"C:\Users\P110095127\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PizzaOrder\PizzaOrder\userDetails.txt";

        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user = "";
            string passcode = "";

            int counter = 0;

            user = usernameBox.Text;
            passcode = passwordBox.Text;

            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(LogIn))
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
                string line;
                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var parts = line.Split(',');
                    user = parts[0];
                    passcode = parts[1];
                    attempts = Convert.ToInt32(parts[3]) + 1;

                    if (user == parts[1])
                    {
                        usernameSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The username is incorrect");
                        attempts++;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (passcode == parts[2])
                    {
                        passwordSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The password is incorrect");
                        attempts++;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (attempts == 3)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The account has been blocked!");
                        this.Hide();
                    }

                    if (usernameSuccess && passwordSuccess == true)
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        Order Order = new Order();
                        Order.Show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want the code to first check if the username is correct, if it is then continue to password, else I want the to display that the username has been entered incorrectly. The same thing goes for password. I have created a variable called 'attempts' and I want to increment the attempts by 1 every time they get username or password wrong. If the attempts reaches 3 then the account will be blocked.

Every time I enter the correct username and password I still get the error message 'The username is incorrect'. Also, after 3 failed attempts it still doesn't hide the window but instead keeps saying the username is incorrect.

Comment: Why not using ```File.ReadAllText()``` or ```File.ReadAllLines()```

Comment: ```user = parts[0];```
```passcode = parts[1];```
```if (user == parts[1])```
this seems broken. You are overwriting you users input

Comment: I also hope this is for a school project or something. This is an awful way to handle security.

Comment: I'm using StreamReader because that's the only way I know how to do it. I wasn't aware of `File.ReadAllText()` and `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: Just curious. What stops any user from opening the text file and using it to gain unauthorized access?

Comment: @Blast_dan It is, I'm just trying to learn how to use text file system.

Comment: Please add a sample of your file content. And how many lines are in that file? Do you have many users to check for or just one?

Comment: This is rather strange logic: enter user name,  check it, and then enter the password.

Comment: @RacilHilan I'm not publishing anything, its for personal use and only will I use it.

Comment: The way you're doing it reading line by line performs better than using `File.ReadAllText()` or `File.ReadAllLines()`, so I would keep that code.

Comment: If you're the only user, then why do you need a login?

Comment: @RacilHilan Because I'm learning how to use StreamReader.

Comment: Oh, I see. So it is a project to learn. You should've stated that in your question so we don't waste your time and ours with comments about security. I think you're using it very well, but see the answers for some possible enhancements.

Comment: This code has at least two more bugs to fix after the one solved in the accepted answer. You will never get three attempts to use the correct user/pass combination. You try to read the attempts value at an index that doesn't exist (according to the sample shown in the accepted answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're implementing the if statements correctly.

```
user = parts[0];
passcode = parts[1];
```

You're storing the data from 0 index in user. And 1 index to passcode.

However, in the ifs you're comparing user to parts[1]? This code is very confusing. Also, please post the content of the txt file so we can see what's being stored in the parts variable.

Edit: If anything you could be doing the following:

1. Remove these lines

   ```
   user = parts[0];
   passcode = parts[1];
   ```
2. Change the ifs to the following:

   ```
   if (usernameBox.Text == parts[0])

   if (passwordBox.Text == parts[1])
   ```

Also I would highly recommend you Trim() strings you read from files because there might be buffer dumps or escape characters in it, best safe than sorry.

Edit 2: I'm pretty sure the following line of code will give you an Index Out Of Bounds exception:

```
attempts = Convert.ToInt32(parts[3]) + 1;
```

It should be:
    attempts = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) + 1;

Comment: I commend you, all those array index's assigned were hard to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking requires the username and password to be in the exact location you're grabbing via your index.  Also, if you have any other text on that line it will hinder your login.

You need to sanitize the data within the document.  For instance:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadByLine(string path)
{
     string line;
     using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
          while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
               yield return line;
}
```

You read each line in the above method.

```
var document = ReadByLine(path);
var username = document.Select(phrase => String.Compare(phrase, user, true) == 0);
var password = document.Select(phrase => String.Compare(phrase, password, true) == 0);
```

The above will iterate through your document, searching for the username and password.  To ensure it exist, now you can actually see if username and password were even found and can correctly ensure they match.

As denoted above, this is a horrible approach for security.  Also, your issue stems from incorrect choice for your variable by index assignment.

*Important:* A direct fix has already been written by Ceasar, this is to simply emphasize the importance of data sanitizing, especially in documents.  You can introduce an assortment of issues by not doing data sanitizing.